# How to use scala nodes?

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.11, I want to use:

```
val responseBody: NodeSeq =
            <html><body><h1>Hello</h1></body></html>;
```

But NodeSeq appears undefined in scala.xml.NodeSeq, which doesnt exist when i attempt to import it. Is it some separate library or removed since Scala 2.11 and is only available in 2.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same `NodeSeq` but it's been moved to the external [scala-xml](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml) library; add a dependency on that and you can continue to use it.